# Getting data from JSON passed by POST method with javascript

Tags: json, post

The problem is that when my PHP file gets the data sent by Method post reads:

```
$play=$_POST['players'];
```

And the result is:

```
"[{'type_player': 'Hombres Bestia' ,'mo': 6, 'st': 3, 'de': 3, 'ar': 8, 'N': 'FGM' , 'D': 'AP' , 'price': 60000, 'habs': [20], 'max_number': 16 }, {'type_player': 'Guerreros del Caos' ,'mo': 5, 'st': 4, 'de': 3, 'ar': 9, 'N': 'FGM' , 'D': 'AP' , 'price': 100000, 'habs': [], 'max_number': 4 }, {'type_player': 'Minotauro' ,'mo': 5, 'st': 5, 'de': 2, 'ar': 8, 'N': 'FM' , 'D': 'AGP' , 'price': 150000, 'habs': [3,15,20,32,34,71], 'max_number': 1 }, {'type_player': 'qwe' ,'mo': 2, 'st': 3, 'de': 4, 'ar': 5, 'N': 'P' , 'D': 'M' , 'price': 132, 'habs': [0], 'max_number': 2 }]"
```

And when I json_decode,

```
$players=json_decode($play,true);
```

it returns:

```
[{'type_player': 'Hombres Bestia' ,'mo': 6, 'st': 3, 'de': 3, 'ar': 8, 'N': 'FGM' , 'D': 'AP' , 'price': 60000, 'habs': [20], 'max_number': 16 }, {'type_player': 'Guerreros del Caos' ,'mo': 5, 'st': 4, 'de': 3, 'ar': 9, 'N': 'FGM' , 'D': 'AP' , 'price': 100000, 'habs': [], 'max_number': 4 }, {'type_player': 'Minotauro' ,'mo': 5, 'st': 5, 'de': 2, 'ar': 8, 'N': 'FM' , 'D': 'AGP' , 'price': 150000, 'habs': [3,15,20,32,34,71], 'max_number': 1 }, {'type_player': 'qwe' ,'mo': 2, 'st': 3, 'de': 4, 'ar': 5, 'N': 'P' , 'D': 'M' , 'price': 132, 'habs': [0], 'max_number': 2 }]
```

The problem is that when I try to get anything in php I cannot. For example:

```
echo "mo:".$players[0]['mo'];
```

It returns:

```
mo:[
```

Any help?

As you suggested I've changed the way I send the data, and now when I $_POST it returns:

"`[{\"type_player\": \"Hombres Bestia\" ,\"mo\": 6, \"st\": 3, \"de\": 3, \"ar\": 8, \"N\": \"FGM\" , \"D\": \"AP\" , \"price\": 60000, \"habs\": [20], \"max_number\": 16 }, {\"type_player\": \"Guerreros del Caos\" ,\"mo\": 5, \"st\": 4, \"de\": 3, \"ar\": 9, \"N\": \"FGM\" , \"D\": \"AP\" , \"price\": 100000, \"habs\": [], \"max_number\": 4 }, {\"type_player\": \"Minotauro\" ,\"mo\": 5, \"st\": 5, \"de\": 2, \"ar\": 8, \"N\": \"FM\" , \"D\": \"AGP\" , \"price\": 150000, \"habs\": [3,15,20,32,34,71], \"max_number\": 1 }, {\"type_player\": \"qdwqw\" ,\"mo\": 2, \"st\": 2, \"de\": 2, \"ar\": 1, \"N\": \"P\" , \"D\": \"F\" , \"price\": 13244, \"habs\": [0], \"max_number\": 1 }]"`

I decode it and it returns:

```
[{"type_player": "Hombres Bestia" ,"mo": 6, "st": 3, "de": 3, "ar": 8, "N": "FGM" , "D": "AP" , "price": 60000, "habs": [20], "max_number": 16 }, {"type_player": "Guerreros del Caos" ,"mo": 5, "st": 4, "de": 3, "ar": 9, "N": "FGM" , "D": "AP" , "price": 100000, "habs": [], "max_number": 4 }, {"type_player": "Minotauro" ,"mo": 5, "st": 5, "de": 2, "ar": 8, "N": "FM" , "D": "AGP" , "price": 150000, "habs": [3,15,20,32,34,71], "max_number": 1 }, {"type_player": "qdwqw" ,"mo": 2, "st": 2, "de": 2, "ar": 1, "N": "P" , "D": "F" , "price": 13244, "habs": [0], "max_number": 1 }]
```

Now, ith should work, but when I try to get the data, the result is the same... Further answers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you json is not valid because the json values are enclosed by double quotes not single quotes

Comment: So, If I change the $play variable with this: $play=str_replace("'",'"',$play); And then I decode, will it work? It does not.

Comment: but you need to sent formated json data . using this is $play=str_replace("'",'"',$play); not gud if any values have with single quotes means its replaced by double quotes so you would't do like this

Comment: So, what do you suggest? You're telling me the problem, but I don't see the solution. I¡ll thank you if you help me

Comment: try my update 2 its working as you expected

Comment: I really thank your advices, but I've updated the entry text here, and as you'll see it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Your `json` is not valid because the json values are enclosed by double quotes not single quotes

**NOTE :** Strings should be wrapped in double quotes.

```
    <?php

    $play='[{"type_player": "Hombres Bestia" ,"mo": 6, "st": 3, "de": 3, "ar": 8, "N": "FGM" , "D": "AP" , "price": 60000, "habs": [20], "max_number": 16 }, {"type_player": "Guerreros del Caos" ,"mo": 5, "st": 4, "de": 3, "ar": 9, "N": "FGM" , "D": "AP" , "price": 100000, "habs": [], "max_number": 4 }, {"type_player": "Minotauro" ,"mo": 5, "st": 5, "de": 2, "ar": 8, "N": "FM" , "D": "AGP" , "price": 150000, "habs": [3,15,20,32,34,71], "max_number": 1 }, {"type_player": "qwe" ,"mo": 2, "st": 3, "de": 4, "ar": 5, "N": "P" , "D": "M" , "price": 132, "habs": [0], "max_number": 2 }]';

    $players=json_decode($play,true);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($players);

    echo $players[0]['mo'];

    ?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [type_player] => Hombres Bestia
                [mo] => 6
                [st] => 3
                [de] => 3
                [ar] => 8
                [N] => FGM
                [D] => AP
                [price] => 60000
                [habs] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 20
                    )

                [max_number] => 16
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [type_player] => Guerreros del Caos
                [mo] => 5
                [st] => 4
                [de] => 3
                [ar] => 9
                [N] => FGM
                [D] => AP
                [price] => 100000
                [habs] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [max_number] => 4
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [type_player] => Minotauro
                [mo] => 5
                [st] => 5
                [de] => 2
                [ar] => 8
                [N] => FM
                [D] => AGP
                [price] => 150000
                [habs] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 3
                        [1] => 15
                        [2] => 20
                        [3] => 32
                        [4] => 34
                        [5] => 71
                    )

                [max_number] => 1
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [type_player] => qwe
                [mo] => 2
                [st] => 3
                [de] => 4
                [ar] => 5
                [N] => P
                [D] => M
                [price] => 132
                [habs] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                    )

                [max_number] => 2
            )

    )

    6
```

UPDATE 2:

you just copy paste the follwoing code in following link able to see the right solution http://phpfiddle.org/

```
        <?php
        $play="[{\"type_player\": \"Hombres Bestia\" ,\"mo\": 6, \"st\": 3, \"de\": 3, \"ar\": 8, \"N\": \"FGM\" , \"D\": \"AP\" , \"price\": 60000, \"habs\": [20], \"max_number\": 16 }, {\"type_player\": \"Guerreros del Caos\" ,\"mo\": 5, \"st\": 4, \"de\": 3, \"ar\": 9, \"N\": \"FGM\" , \"D\": \"AP\" , \"price\": 100000, \"habs\": [], \"max_number\": 4 }, {\"type_player\": \"Minotauro\" ,\"mo\": 5, \"st\": 5, \"de\": 2, \"ar\": 8, \"N\": \"FM\" , \"D\": \"AGP\" , \"price\": 150000, \"habs\": [3,15,20,32,34,71], \"max_number\": 1 }, {\"type_player\": \"qdwqw\" ,\"mo\": 2, \"st\": 2, \"de\": 2, \"ar\": 1, \"N\": \"P\" , \"D\": \"F\" , \"price\": 13244, \"habs\": [0], \"max_number\": 1 }]";


        $players=json_decode($play,true);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($players);

        ?>
```

Comment: I do not get it. I cannot write the first line of code, cos I get the data from $_POST[""]. After this, the results are the same. I cannot get the data

Comment: echo $_POST['playes']; and copy the output and paste it here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and know the what is the error with your json data

Comment: :( sadly it works with echo $players. It says to me that is a vàlid json, but when I try $players[0]["mo"] I only get [. If I try $players[1]["mo"] I only get {

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

**`JSON`** notation is written with double quotes.As a side note, the [JSON data exchange format](http://json.org/) does require double quotes around identifiers.

```
<?php
$play = '[
  { 
    "type_player": "Hombres Bestia" ,
    "mo": 6, 
    "st": 3, 
    "de": 3, 
    "ar": 8, 
    "N": "FGM" , 
    "D": "AP" , 
    "price": 60000, 
    "habs": [20], 
    "max_number": 16 
  },
  {
    "type_player": "Guerreros del Caos" ,
    "mo": 5, 
    "st": 4, 
    "de": 3, 
    "ar": 9, 
    "N": "FGM" , 
    "D": "AP" , 
    "price": 100000, 
    "habs": [], "max_number": 4 
  },
  { 
    "type_player": "Minotauro" ,
    "mo": 5, 
    "st": 5, 
    "de": 2, 
    "ar": 8, 
    "N": "FM" , 
    "D": "AGP" , 
    "price": 150000, 
    "habs": [3,15,20,32,34,71], 
    "max_number": 1 
  }, 
  {
    "type_player": "qwe" ,
    "mo": 2, 
    "st": 3, 
    "de": 4, 
    "ar": 5, 
    "N": "P" , 
    "D": "M" , 
    "price": 132, 
    "habs": [0], 
    "max_number": 2 
    }
]';

$players = json_decode($play,true);

echo $players[0]['mo'];

?>
```

**Output :** **`6`**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've UPDATED the text above, and as you'll see having double quotes around identifiers do not solve the problem, Do you know why?

Comment: What error you getting in console. As you can see in the answer every thing is working fine.